# Finding a duplicate row based on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm having some difficulty figuring how to go about doing this.

I'm processing a rather large XLSX file (roughly 350,000 rows with 40 columns). The client requested that we ignore any rows that already exist within our database.

I've done this, but the ignore check is quite literally increasing the processing time by around 5 hours. And I know there has to be a more efficient way to go about doing this.

I'm using Doctrine.

```
SELECT 1 from company_activity where product_id = :product_id and
                 applicationnumber = :applicationnumber and accountidentifier = :accountidentifier and startdate = :startdate and
                 activitydate = :activitydate and company_id = :company_id and companyemployee = :companyemployee and promotion = :promotion and
                 employee_id = :employee_id and productsalesrep_id = :productsalesrep_id limit 0, 1
```

I'm not surprised this is slow, but am not really certain how else to go about doing it. I found a lot of threads for finding duplicates, but for finding all duplicates within a table, not for finding if a single record has a similar entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you defined any indexes on table ?

Comment: Just the ID columns. If I index almost every column in the table, doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose?  It might increase performance a little bit, but I don't imagine the overall difference would be significant. 

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not individual index you need to define composite index including all columns which appear in where clause like index(product_id,applicationnumber,....). It might give you better performance

Comment: I tried working these in, but the main issue is it requires a default value be set for all the indexed columns. It's relatively important they are set to NULL by default.

Comment: so you are doing 350,000 individual queries? through PHP and "doctrine" (whatever that is), why not just load the xlsx into another table? and then run one query.....

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? There is significant amount of processing that takes place for each row, I'm just just loading the XLSX into the table. 

Doctrine is a ORM

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html